# recursive range function not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to teach myself recursion by doing a range function recursively.  I can't understand why the code below isn't working?

Iterative version:

```js
function rangeList(num, num2) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = num; i < num2; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Recursive version:

```js
function rangeRecursive(num, num2) {
  return (num2 > num) ? rangeRecursive(num2 - 1).concat(num2) : []
}

console.log(rangeList(1, 7)); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(rangeRecursive(1, 7)); // returns [7]
```

Comment: Your're calling `rangeRecursive` with only one parameter inside the method.

Comment: This should not have been that hard to debug. Place a breakpoint at the `return (num2 > num) ...` line. Examining local variables would have shown you that `num2` was undefined. From there, it would have been a quick step to figuring out that you were failing to pass `num2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are missing a parameter in your recursive call

It should be like this

```
function rangeRecursive(num, num2) {
  return (num2 >= num) ? rangeRecursive(num /*this was missing*/, num2 - 1).concat(num2) : []
}
```

Also notice the changed condition on the ternary, otherwise it stops at 1 and doesn't concat it. Either you can use `>=` or the following

```
return num2 > num ? rangeRecursive(num, num2 - 1).concat(num2) : [num]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parameter in your recursive function. It should be like this:

```
function rangeRecursive(num, num2) 
{
  return num2 > num ? rangeRecursive(num, num2 - 1).concat(num2) : [num]
}
```